# Is my proof of $\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty }{ \frac { x+8 }{ x+3 } =1 } $ correct?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { x+8 }{ x+3 } =1 } $$

Proof: Let $\epsilon > 0$

$$\left| \frac { x+8 }{ x+3 } -1 \right| <\epsilon $$

$$\Longrightarrow \left| \frac { x+8 }{ x+3 } -\frac { x+3 }{ x+3 }  \right| <\epsilon $$

$$\Longrightarrow \left| \frac { 5 }{ x+3 }  \right| <\epsilon $$

$$\Longrightarrow \frac { 5 }{ \left| x+3 \right|  } <\epsilon $$

Without loss of generality, assume that $x>-3$

Then, we get: $$\frac { 5 }{ x+3 } <\epsilon $$

$$\Longrightarrow 5< \epsilon (x+3)$$

$$\Longrightarrow 5<\epsilon x+3\epsilon $$

$$\Longrightarrow \epsilon x>5-3\epsilon $$

$$\Longrightarrow x>\frac { 5 }{ \epsilon  } -3$$

This concludes my proof, but I still have so many questions. I feel like a computer when I'm doing this. I don't truly understand what I'm doing and I know that this will come back to haunt me at some point.

So, some of the things that I want clarification on:

1) If my proof is even correct and complete

2) Why I should assume that $x>-3$ It seems very arbitrary.

3) What exactly this all means and why did it prove what I was asked.

Comment: I would replace your "$\Longrightarrow$" with "if and only if"  i.e., "$\Longleftrightarrow$": You want "x big implies the fraction is close to one" -  agree? And to answer your second question, you assume $x>-3$ so that your algebra works, and because you can...

Comment: @peterag Can you please clarify what you said? Perhaps in an answer?

Comment: OK - give me a second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assert 
$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { x+8 }{ x+3 } =1 }$$
is to say, in casual words, that if $x$ is large, that the fraction is close to $1$. In math legalese, it is to say that given an $\epsilon >0$, one can find an $L$ such that $x > L$ implies
 $$ \left| \frac { x+8 }{ x+3 } -1 \right| <\epsilon.$$
Your algebra is really calculating $L$:
$$ L = {\frac { 5 }{ \epsilon  }} -3.$$

So you really want to convince the reader, that if he or she starts with the last line of your argument, and read it backwards, (i.e., with your arrow $\Longrightarrow$ replaced with $\Longleftarrow$, so that a given line implies the preceding), they arrive at the conclusion that the fraction is within $\epsilon$ of $1$.

On the other hand, you figured out your $L$ in the order that you wrote down your argument - of course... So either you use $\Longleftrightarrow$ (so both you and your reader are happy), or you secretly do, on the side, your calculation, and write the argument, starting with if

$  x> {\frac { 5 }{ \epsilon  }} -3$, then ...., concluding with the "we are forced to conclude the fraction is within  $\epsilon$ of $1$ - proving that the limit is $1$, as desired."

OK?

Comment: Obviously @Milo and I are saying the same thing... Hope this helps - you might be better going over this 'face to face' with your lecturer... It is hard first to get the hang of this. Math really does have a similar character to law, on occasion.

Comment: You are saying that if I replace my $\Longrightarrow $ with $\Longleftrightarrow $, I would be correct?

Comment: Yes: as @Milo explained, you can, because all of your steps are reversible - you would be correct. BUT, as you point out in your question, it's more important is that you understand why it's ok -  a "if" step  is not always the same as an "if and only if" step. In this particular case, they happen to be. BUT - again, what you want is that your reader  conclude that for arbitrary  positive $\epsilon$ one an impose a largeness condition on $x$ so that the fraction is within $\epsilon$ of  $1$.

Comment: As you already mentioned, it's hard to get the hang of this. Can you look at the last comment I left under @Milo 's answer? What can you say about what I wrote there?

Comment: Yes: You can say, right before the "without loss of generality" line, that you are now calculating the lower bound on $x$ (the $N$) to force the preceding (i.e. less than $\epsilon$ ) to hold true... You still need to have the $\Longleftrightarrow$s though... Before the "without loss of generality" line, e.g., this is the case, because the terms on LHS haven't changed  - OK? I hope so because I'm afraid I have to run... Again, it would be better face to face: ask your lecturer...

Answer (score 2):

Your proof has the right idea, but proceeds in the wrong direction. In particular, to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=c$ you need that there is some $N$ so that for any $x>N$ we have $|f(x)-c|<\varepsilon$. Now, you've got all the elements together, but what you have is:

> If $|f(x)-c|<\varepsilon$ then $x>N$.

which is distinct from what you need:

> If $x>N$ then $|f(x)-c|<\varepsilon.$

Now, all of your steps are reversible, so you can just write your proof in reverse and be correct. Notice that your proof implicitly sets $N=\frac{5}{\varepsilon}-3$, which is why that numbers is important.

Also, as to why you assume $x>-3$ that's just so that you don't have to deal with the vertical asymptote at $x=3$. You can do that since you only care about how "large" $x$ act.

Comment: Ok. I think I kind of understand but, I don't get how my proof should look. I found $N$, so should I just write a conclusion with it? Or what? This is hard to wrap my head around.

Comment: A proof could start with with "For any $\varepsilon>0$ set $N=\frac{5}{\varepsilon}-3$ and let $x>N$" then be followed by algebra to show $|\frac{x+8}{x+3}-1|<\varepsilon$. Basically, just follow the quantifiers - you are obliged to show some way to get from any $\varepsilon$ to a valid $N$, so start out by making $N$ explicit if you can. Once you've done that, show that the $N$ satisfies the condition.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is so confusing. So I just need to algebraically manipulate $ x>\frac { 5 }{ \epsilon  } -3$ to get to $|\frac{x+8}{x+3}-1|<\varepsilon$?

Comment: Since I wasn't given my $N$, can't I start the proof the way I did and then end it with something like: Therefore, since  $ x>\frac { 5 }{ \epsilon  } -3$, we can conclude that $|\frac{x+8}{x+3}-1|<\varepsilon\Longleftrightarrow x>\frac { 5 }{ \epsilon  } -3$ 

It just seems very weird to exclude how I got $N$ from the proof since it wans't given